# Logarithm problem

Tags: logarithms

If $a^x=b^y$, then how come $x\log a=y\log b$ holds? Can anyone show me how this is with all steps and necessary logarithm formula?

Comment: $\log x^r=r\log x$.

Comment: @DavidMitra-can you please say what is 'a'?

Comment: Had a typo at first; it's the correct formula now. Take logs of both sides of your equation and apply the above formula.

Comment: @DavidMitra-That was why I was not being able to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log a^x = \log \overbrace{(a\cdot a \cdots \cdots a)}^x = \log a + \log a + \cdots \cdots + \log a = x\log a$

Since $a^x  = b^y\quad $ so $\quad \log a^x = \log b^y \implies x\log a = y\log b$